# include variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I need some help with the following.

I have a script that close down the web page using the following:

```
<a href=\"Javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"parent.location.reload();window.parent.Shadowbox.close();\">
```

It works as it should. My problem is that I need to change parent to another page. For this I used the following:

```
<a href=\"Javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"parent.location='http://www.google.com';window.parent.Shadowbox.close();\">
```

It also works, but now I do not want it to go to google but one of my pages where it should include a variable. Normally I would use:

```
<?=$array["id"]?>
```

But since it is a javascript then I cant use PHP and the following solution does not work:

```
<a href=\"Javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"parent.location='new-new.php?$array[‘id’];window.parent.Shadowbox.close();\">
```

So I tried this:

```
function getNewURL() {
    var root="http://minside.net";
    var id="topic/#entry667119";
    var nURL=root+"/"+id;
    return nURL;
}
```

With the javascript:

```
<a href=\"Javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"parent.location.replace(getNewURL);window.parent.Shadowbox.close();\">
```

For in this way to get my variables with me, but it does not work.

Someone who can help me? Or have another idea for how to resolve this?

Comment: That will become messy quick. My advice, add your events _in JavaScript_ and print a JSON object in PHP that you can use in your JS code.

Comment: @elclanrs now to php and javacript so I have no idea of what you referring to. Can you coame some examples?

Answer (score 0):

**you can assign a php variable to javascript variable**.

```
var a=<?php echo $array[‘id’]?>;
```

Comment: can you show how it will like. The code I have so fare is: if(strlen($large_photo_exists)>0 && strlen($thumb_photo_exists)>0){
 echo "<center><br><h2>This is your new profile image</h2><b>";
 echo $thumb_photo_exists;
 echo "<p><a href=\"Javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"parent.location='page.php?id=v';window.parent.Shadowbox.close();\">Use this photo as my profile photo</a></p>";
 echo "<br> OR <br>";
 echo "<p><a href=\"".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?id=".$_GET["id"]."&a=delete&t=".$_SESSION['random_key'].$_SESSION['user_file_ext']."\">Upload and use another photo</a></p>";

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [echo](https://www.php.net/echo):

```
<? echo $array["id"]; ?>
```

**Edit**

```
var id = <?php echo $array["id"]; ?>;
var link = "<a href=\"Javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"parent.location='new-new.php?id="+id+";window.parent.Shadowbox.close();\">";
```

assuming you use `$_GET['id']` in `new-new.php` (you omitted it in the URL)

**Edit**

```
if(strlen($large_photo_exists) > 0 && strlen($thumb_photo_exists) > 0)
{
    echo $thumb_photo_exists;
    echo "<p><a href=\"Javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"parent.location='page.php?id={$_GET["id"]}';window.parent.Shadowbox.close();\">Use this photo as my profile photo</a></p>";
    echo "<br> OR <br>";
    echo "<p><a href=\"" . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?id=" . $_GET["id"] . "&a=delete&t=" . $_SESSION['rando‌​m_key'] . $_SESSION['user_file_ext'] . "\">Upload and use another photo</a></p>";
}
```

Comment: always be careful with shorthand representation.

Comment: @Mr Indeed. I would not use it myself.

Comment: if I use: <? echo $array['id']; ?> then i need to \$ and then it dont Work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes I use that. But im not sure how to add your codes to mine. Here is what I have so fare. if(strlen($large_photo_exists)>0 && strlen($thumb_photo_exists)>0){
 echo $thumb_photo_exists;
 echo "<p><a href=\"Javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"parent.location='page.php?id=v';window.parent.Shadowbox.close();\">Use this photo as my profile photo</a></p>";
 echo "<br> OR <br>";
 echo "<p><a href=\"".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?id=".$_GET["id"]."&a=delete&t=".$_SESSION['random_key'].$_SESSION['user_file_ext']."\">Upload and use another photo</a></p>";

Answer (score 0):

you are using echo for that right since you use `\` for `"`, so it should be like this:

```
<a href=\"Javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"parent.location='new-new.php?'.$array[‘id’]'.window.parent.Shadowbox.close();\">
```

Comment: cant use the: .$array[‘id’] I need to change it to \.$array[‘id’] and it will not call the virable

Answer (score 0):

The best way to assign a variable in Javascript is

```
var id = <?php echo json_encode($array["id"]); ?>
```